# Testing delegate callbacks using Jasmine (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I have a simple JavaScript function that uses two delegates to (asynchronously) get one value back:

```
function getMyUserName() {
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onGetMyUserNameSuccess, onGetMyUserNameFail);
}
function onGetMyUserNameSuccess() {
    return user.get_title();
}
function onGetMyUserNameFail(sender, args) {
    return args.get_message();
}
```

The "context" and "user" variables are already set and initialized, and the first delegate ("onGetMyUserNameSuccess") is getting the correct answer. The question is how I can test the "getMyUserName" function with Jasmine?. If I use "runs", I have no way to know the response from the delegates (also I don't see any way to know if the delegates are called). I tried to set spies to mock the delegates, but probably I didn't it correctly (I'm just starting with Jasmine).
Any help will be very welcome.
Thanks in advance,
Gustavo

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases when you have to work with async code, you should call the function by yourself. But not directly but in the way your code would call it. So in your case spy on `context.executeQueryAsync` and use `spy.mostRecentCall.args` to get the reference to the function and then call them.

```
var async = jasmin.spyOn(context, 'executeQueryAsync');

async.mostRecentCall.args[0]()

var args = {get_message: jasmine.createSpy()}
async.mostRecentCall.args[1]({}, args);
expect(args.get_message.toHaveBeenCalled());
```

Note that there is the [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) framework that have a [bunch of methodes](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs) to automatically call callbacks